# Laravel - Overwrite magic _get method for a custom Request class

Tags: laravel, magic-methods

I have a custom request class `PersonRequest` where I use for an exporting project where I manipulate the original request and create new ones, I need to overwrite the default magic `get` method for Request

I can call `$request->get($key)` and I already overwrited that method in my `PersonRequest`, but:

## How do I overwrite `$request->key`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see [here](https://github.com/illuminate/http/blob/master/Request.php#L695) how Laravel implemented it and, by following that method'signature, you can put the custom `__get` magic method in the same class where you have placed your custom `get` method.

Maybe if you provide more details about what you are trying to achieve, there might be an easier way to solve the problem instead of overriding the request class.

Comment: Your answer woked for me, let me explain to you what I'm trying to do here, in my API i can pass a json to export multiple data (in this case a person) and inside each person in the json can have multiples relations, addresses, users, etc... So I need to extract each person of the json, test if this person already exists or not (so I need to update or create a new one), and create a new request based on that person data retrieved from the request, so I can use the same `create` method from the PersonsController to create a new person, address, etc, if I pass the normal `request()` don't work

Comment: So I have a PersonRequest class, I instantiate it with the data from the request, It was working perfect in my tests, `$new_request->key` returned the correct data, but for requests with a content-type of application/json works differently, it doesn't look for the key in `$resquest->request->key` it gets from `$request->json->key` and I don't know how to overwrite this json data

Answer (score 0):

I think you can override the constructor of the `PersonRequest` and change the key as follows:

```php
function __constructor(Request $request){
    $request->key = 'new_key'; //override the key here
}
```

Comment: It's a good option, but in my case it need to be dinamic and work with any key